# go to home page when i select default in select-box

Tags: php, categories, javascript, dropdown

I'm new for WordPress. I'm using following code,

```
<div id="cat_list">
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories(array('show_option_all' => 'Categories') ); ?> 
</div>
```

And my JavaScript is,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
    function onCatChange() {
        if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script>
```

If I select any Category means, that goes to correct page. But my requirement is, Will be go home page when re-select `Categories` (show_option_all).

Any option is in WordPress? other what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
    function onCatChange() {
        if ( dropdown.selectedIndex == 0 ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');?>";
        }else if ( dropdown.selectedIndex > 0 ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script>
```